# I want to delete a certain number of oldest files in a folder with .cmd

Tags: command-line, backup

I have a backup folder where are for everyday day a  Backup-folder (like 15.06.; 14.06; 13.06.....) containing the backup files.

I now want a to delete (in .cmd file) An amount of x oldest folders so that there are still the 30 newest files in folder.

I tried:

```
set Pf_TargetForfiles=Z:\Backups

set AnzahlOrdner=
for /d %%a in (Z:\TargetForfiles\*) do set /a AnzahlOrdner+=1 

If %AnzahlOrdner% GTR 30 forfiles /p "%Pf_ZielForfiles%" /d -42 /c "CMD /c if @isdir==TRUE rd @path  /s /q"
```

Greetings

Edit: what I'm testing right now is this:

```
set Pf_ZielBackup=Z:\Backups\F\WichtigVer\Robo\Version\


echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "_count=0"
rem count the files
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir %Pf_ZielBackup% /a:d /b /o:d') do @(set /a _count+=1 >nul) 

echo !_count! directories found
rem delete _count-27 files
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir %Pf_ZielBackup% /a:d /b /o:d') do (
    set /a _count-=1
    echo directory !_count! is %%a
    echo rd /q %%a

    if "!_count!"=="27" (
      goto :done
    )
  )
:done
pause
```

**This Code has the - for me - very weird problem that wen i remove the "echo" from `echo rd /q %%a` that then i get an error message from windows** (The system can not find the specified file. But if i run script with "echo" the it lists me in the commandprompt the three oldest files just fine. Anybody knows how to fix this?

**Edit2 Now The script runs but deletes all Folders** - i had to stop it after it deleted 10 Folders (should have deleted 0)... in the Subdirectory- something with the counter logic must be wrong i guess:

```
set Pf_ZielBackup=Z:\Backups\F\WichtigVer\Robo\Version\


echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "_count=0"
rem count the files
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir %Pf_ZielBackup% /a:d /b /o:d') do @(set /a _count+=1 >nul) 

echo !_count! directories found
rem delete _count-30 files
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir %Pf_ZielBackup% /a:d /b /o:d') do (
    set /a _count-=1
    echo directory !_count! is %Pf_ZielBackup%\%%a
    rd /s /q %Pf_ZielBackup%\%%a


    if "!_count!"=="30" (
      goto :done
    )
  )
:done
pause
```

Comment: You should be able to do this with a Powershell script.

Comment: Or a batch file.

Comment: `set Pf_ZielBackup=Z:\Backups\F\WichtigVer\Robo\Version\


echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "_count=0"
rem count the files
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir %Pf_ZielBackup% /a:d /b /o:d') do @(set /a _count+=1 >nul) 

echo !_count! directories found
rem delete _count-27 files
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir %Pf_ZielBackup% /a:d /b /o:d') do (
    set /a _count-=1
    echo directory !_count! is %%a
    echo rd /q %%a

    if "!_count!"=="27" (
      goto :done
    )
  )
:done
pause`

Answer (score 1):

As Ramhound said in his comment, the easiest way to achieve this goal is to use PowerShell. Here is a simple script to do so :

```
$list = Get-ChildItem -Path c:\temp  | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -Last 10
$list | Remove-Item -Force -WhatIf
```

This script will delete the 10 oldest files in the C:\Temp folder. Note the **-Whatif** parameter allows you to check what this command will do, without actually doing it. Simply remove this parameter when you are ready to perform the operation.

Of course, you can make this script [running in a Scheduled Task](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/08/11/weekend-scripter-use-the-windows-task-scheduler-to-run-a-windows-powershell-script.aspx), just like you do with exe or batch files.

**[UPDATE] :** As the title was confusing, here is the update of my answer :

```
$dnd = Get-ChildItem -Path c:\Test -Directory | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | select -last 2
$list = Get-ChildItem -Path c:\Test -Directory 
$list | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -Exclude $dnd -WhatIf
```

**Explanations :**

- the **$dnd** (do not delete) variable will contain the list of folder to keep : in my example, the 2 oldest of the C:\Test directory ;
- the **$list** variable will list all folders under c:\Test ;
- the third line of the script will delete forcefully the folders, excluding all contained in the **$dnd** variable. Don't forget to remove the **-WhatIf** switch when you are sure.

Hope this helps !

Comment: This doesn't delete oldest x leaving 30. And he wants to delete directories not files.

Comment: The question title is : I want to delete a certain number of oldest files in a folder with .cmd. So that's why I posted a command deleting files. In is question he also said : "I now want a to delete (in .cmd file) An amount of x oldest folders", that's why I posted such an answer. Of course he can adapt this at wish to match his goal.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion i caused. I totally mistyped the heading. It must be: ...number of x oldest directories...

Comment: My answer is corrected, thanks to your new exaplanations :) Still shorter and easier to understand than a batch file, isn't it ?

Comment: Hi i checked out your script and its yielding very confusing results: [link] (http://1drv.ms/1BgFRvK) In the tested folder are 21 folders, 13 does the script want to delete. something wrong with the listing or with "lastwritetime" (I have no clue what that is, something like modified date?) Greetings

Comment: @user54512 : lastwritetime is the last time the folder's content has been changed. What value did you specify in the 'select -Last' statement ? I see '2' but maybe you crop the screenshot ?

Comment: It is 2 actually. To give you some context. The Backupfolders are copied with robocopy /copy:DAT /dcopy:T so you have the folder e.g. 15.06.2015 with a created and modified Date of 15.06.2015 ... BUT all files and folders within this folder keep there created and modified date the original file has... Is lastwritetime somewhat cycling through folder, searching for lastwritetime?

Comment: The command I provided filters by the FOLDER lastwritetime, no its content.

Answer (score 0):

#### I want to delete a certain number of oldest directories in a folder

You can use the following batch file:

```
echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "_count=0"
rem count the files
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /a:d /b /o:d') do @(set /a _count+=1 >nul)
echo !_count! directories found
rem delete _count-30 files
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /a:d /b /o:d') do (
    set /a _count-=1
    echo directory !_count! is %%a
    echo rd /q %%a
    if "!_count!"=="30" (
      goto :done
    )
  )
:done
```

How it works:

- use `for /f` with `dir` to get list of directories
- `/a:d` directories only
- use `/b` so we don't count `.` and `..`
- `o:d` order by date (**oldest** first)
- count the directories
- process the list again
- for each match decrement the count
- remove the match
- stop at 30 (leaves 30 directories in place)

Replace `echo rd /q %%a` with `rd /q %%a` when you have finished testing the batch file.

---

#### I'm having trouble getting the path to the directory correct

> If the path is:
>
> `set target=z\backup....`
>
> I tried:
>
> `for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%target% /a:d /b /o:d') do....`

Your attempt is missing the `dir` and the first `'` character. It should be:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir %target% /a:d /b /o:d') do ...
```

Don't forget to change **both** `for /f` commands.

You also need to add `%target%\` to the two echo commands:

```
echo directory !_count! is %target%\%%a
echo rd /q %target%\%%a
```

Comment: I'm having trouble getting the path to the directory in there right. E.g if the path is: set target=z\backup.... I tried: `for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%target% /a:d /b /o:d') do....`

Comment: ??? eg if the path is what exactly? You mean `Z:\TargetForfiles\*? Or `Z:\Backups`? What is the name of the parent directory comtaining the subdirectories to be deleted?

Comment: Ah O.K. its just examples for example Path containing the directories would be: Z\Backups.

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: Hi David, i have some strange problems with your solution. While testing it looked fine then i removed the "echo" an got two problems: 1. Somehow there got a "weird" sign before the "set", the consequence looked scary the srcipt then goes off on my desktop? Could other folders be deleted, if the path is not found?  [link] (http://1drv.ms/1CaHs0I)  After i fixed the error1 i got the 2. Error. In english it says: the system can not find the specified file...[link] (http://1drv.ms/1J1aisv) Any ideas? P.S. Thanks for your help so far...

Comment: Can you edit your question to add a copy of the batch file you are currently testing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24866/discussion-between-davidpostill-and-user54512).